# Derivation of complexity for data encoding schemes

Tags: quantum-gate, complexity-theory, encoding

Could anyone help to derive the space-time complexities of the following different data encoding schemes ?

[image: data_encoding_schemes]

Comment: please edit the post to add a link to the source

Comment: @glS this is captured as a screenshot from IBM online seminar where the organizer does not provide any download-able materials

Comment: https://pennylane.ai/qml/glossary/quantum_embedding might be of interest